# Close a popup modal

Tags: javascript, ajax, modal-dialog, greasemonkey

I have been attempting to get greasemonkey to close a modal by clicking the "x" button. Here is the code for the page.

```
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" onClick="window.location.reload()">x</button>
```

I've tried using `document.querySelector('.close').click()` but to no avail. Where am I going wrong here?

The page in question is running javascript and ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks like bootstrap modal, so look for the main container ID or class name and use the following code.

```
$('#modalID').modal('hide');
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just add the `hide` class to the modal? That's all that clicking it is going to do.